# How to open web page after installation and uninstallation?

Tags: c#, deployment, installation, setup-project

In a setup project i want to automatically open a website directly after the installation finished dialog and uninstallation as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do so. Use Custom Installer to override the Install and UnInstall method in your installer class and in them you can start a new process of opening your web page in IExplore.

A thorough implementation about it can be found at [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146626/Extending-Visual-Studio-Setup-Project)

Comment: i am using the default setup project to do so,
i Googled it with no use,
can you get any link explaining the way you suggested ?

Comment: @HassanWasef: That link is already there in my answer. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146626/Extending-Visual-Studio-Setup-Project

Comment: Thanks i have made it using a batch ".bat" file